# how to call onclick on an external JS file? w/o jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on some web very simple drag and drop game using html5 and javascript. After they drag the elements I have a button that verifies either the arrange is correct or not. My verify function is on an external JS file and I'm calling it using onclick inside the input tag. It works, however my boss doesnt want event handlers to be shown on the html. I'm just starting with javascript so is there a way to call an onclick event without using the onclick on a tag in the html file?

Ive read you can do it easily with jquery, but can you use it without jquery?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using JQuery?

Comment: I'm very new to javascript, I'm mostly flash/as3 designer so I will have to investigate a lot to get used to Jquery.

Comment: *Something* has to trigger the function that you are calling in your onclick event.  I have to imagine that when you drop your item you have some JavaScript that fires when the item is "dropped".  I would just add a call to your onclick function at the end of the drop.

Comment: I have different things triggering when I drop the images but most are estetic, I have a button that verifies the final answer, the question here is how to use the onclick event trigger without using in inside a tag i.e. <input type="button" value="verificar" id="bVerificar" onclick="moviendo.verificar()"> I need to remove that onclick="moviendo.verificar()" and somehow put it inside my external js file. Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a click event to the button like they do in jquery:

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
    var targetElement = event.target;
    if ( targetElement.className == "myButton" ) {
       // do something
        alert("my button clicked");
    }   

};
```

This example works on a class name but you can change that to any attribute you want on the button or something else.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I just replaced the classname with id. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are two meanings I got from your question.
1) You want to call onclick event of an item on particular thing. 

For this you can directly call the methods you want to call onclick.

2) not showing on html that it has onclick. For this you can use something like this:

```
document.getElementById('id').onClick = "yourMethod()";
```

Hope it helps.